# How to fix pathfinding stuck in curved corridors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm developing a game based on a 2D landscape consisting of hundreds of thousands of small tiles that player characters and enemies can move around. A few days ago I started working on the enemy AI and the first step was to find the path. I chose the Jump Point Search algorithm, and after several days of trying to figure out how the algorithm works, it finally worked.

### "Cursed shape of the corridor"

[image: "Cursed shape of the corridor"]

However, a problem arose almost immediately: in the corridors of a certain shape (screenshot), the simplest heuristics (current path length + distance to the target) determines as "the most promising" absolutely not those nodes that are needed, because of which the algorithm enters not infinite, but very long cycle.

[image: Single white lines are checked nodes. It can be seen that the algorithm did not even enter the desired corridor.]

> Single white lines are checked nodes. It can be seen that the algorithm did not even enter the desired corridor.

Because the entire terrain is dynamic and players can freely place and remove obstacles, I can't avoid these corridors appearing on the map.
Is it possible to solve this problem by reconfiguring the heuristic or something else?
If there are no easy solutions with the same pathfinding algorithm, what algorithm should be used instead?

Comment: If you have issues with "Jump Point", revert to A* and verify that *it* works. If you have issues with A*, revert to Djikstra and check that *it* works. A dynamic map should not really be a problem for A*, but I'm not familiar with "Jump Point", so I cannot tell if that will have issues or not.

Comment: it is not entirely clear in the second picture where you expected the path to be. Nor what you are dong to generate your path

Comment: Unfortunately, the simpler A* starts to lag incredibly badly even earlier due to how many tiles there are. That's why I had to use JPS.

Comment: In the second image, it is expected that the path will pass from above through the same corridor (it just shows part of the map a little lower than in the previous screenshot).
To build a path, I simply search for the next tiles until the target is found, and for each node I store which previous node can be reached from.
Also, is there any way to reply to a specific comment here?

Comment: Much as JonasH pointed out, if someones a* doesnt work it maybe someone elses or you need to write your own.  There are a number of things that can be done to speed up processing  if the code is changable and understood. Code monkey I think did one on on moving it to a job. However, not everyones code is the same and perhaps the one you picked is not good on bigger maps

Comment: I basically understand the code I wrote and it works pretty well for most of the map. But it is in corridors of this shape, no matter how far apart the enemy and its target are, that the algorithm always gets stuck and looks for a way in a absolutely different part of the map.
In any case, are there any good tutorials for pathfinding on these types of maps? I tried to find them, but without success.